# Is lock released when non synchronised method is called

Tags: java, multithreading

If i have a methodA which is synchronized

```
public synchronized void methodA() {
    // ... Some code
    methodB();
    // ... Some more code
}
```

I have a methodB which is not synchronized and called from methodA

```
private void methodB() {
    // ...
}
```

Thread will acquire a lock and enter into methodA. My doubt is when methodB is called from methodA is the lock released and acquired again when controll goes back to methodA.

Comment: No, it's not, methodA will hold the lock as long as it has not completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The only method which does this is Object.wait();

e.g.

```
public synchronized void methodA() {
    // ... Some code
    // releases the lock, waits 1000 ms or until notify()ed, & regains the lock.
    wait(1000); 
    // .. some code.
    methodB(); // doesn't do anything to the lock
    // ... Some more code
}
```

Note: as it DOESN'T release the lock you have the possibility of a deadlock with multiple locks.

```
class MyClass {
    public synchronized void methodA(MyClass mc) {
         mc.methodB();
    }

    public synchronized void methodB() {
         // something
    }
}

static MyClass MC1 = new MyClass(), MC2 = new MyClass();
```

If you have one thread which calls

```
MC1.methodA(MC2);
```

and another which calls

```
MC2.methodA(MC1);
```

you can get a deadlock.  This is because first method locks one object and the second call locks the other.  As the thread do this in different orders, it is possible for each thread to hold the lock the other one needs.

Comment: Object.wait() releases the lock during wait(1000). Does it acquire the lock again?

Comment: @Octopus I have updated the answer. It re-acquires the lock (or waits until it can) even if interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Does it make a difference if in my code methodB is public or private.

Comment: @nascent none, only `static` makes a difference for locking.